# How to get a smooth cone shape?

Tags: modeling, unity

I wanted to make a button like this :

[image]

And was able to create this button :

[image]
[image]

But obviously, the shape is not really smooth (I'm talking about the star shape in the center). I already applied a subdivision surface modifier, so this model has already 22k vertices which is way too much I guess. I hope, that there is a better solution to achieve a smooth cone. This model will be exported to Unity so the solution should be exportable (I think stuff like "smooth shading" is not exportable since it's not applied in the model, right?)

This is the model without the modifier :

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you highlight what you think is unsmooth. Also, could you show it in 3d?

Comment: It seems that this problem occurs, because I've got a mix of triangles and quads and the subdivision surface modifier doesn't handle that too good... But I can't see how I should fix this for this model..

Comment: Smooth shading is exportable and should be used here. To make center part free of the star-like lines delete faces there, select the creased edge loop (or the one closer to the center, depend on the shape you're aiming to) and use Ctrl+F > GridFill. It will fill that area with quads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't smooth because the center part has one vertex, try to change the center part into a circle (to fill, use either press the button <kbd>F</kbd> or go to *Mesh*--> *Faces* --> *Fill* and add loop cuts with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I edited my answer :)

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can just keep them there :)

Answer (score 2):

The Problem here is as mentioned the one vertex pole. Have you tried to fill the center like this? (don't mind the rest of this model as it has a bad topology)
[image]

The center looks smooth as seen below.
[image]